# Bind a template to a ng-container

Tags: angular

Is it possible to bind a `ng-template` reference to a `ng-container`, like on the `if..else` usage?

For instance, what I have is:

```
<section class="section_one">
  <ng-container
    *ngIf="someCondition"
    bind-template="someTemplate"
  >
  </ng-container>
</section>

...

<section class="section_two">
  <ng-container
    *ngIf="!someCondition"
    bind-template="someTemplate"
  >
  </ng-container>
</section>

...

<ng-template #someTemplate>
  ...
</ng-template>
```

I want to know if there's something like the `bind-template` already built-in. The documentation for both `ng-container` and `ng-template` doesn't exist yet.

So, basically, depending on the scenario this template appear in section one, or on the two. I know that I could create a component for it, but I don't want it because this template is completely related to the current component. What I want is to display the data from the template in different areas, accordingly of this condition.

I can achieve it using `if..else` on the `ng-container`, but it seems a little weird, as the conditions must be inverted.

```
<section class="section_one">
  <ng-container *ngIf="!someCondition; else someTemplate">
  </ng-container>
</section>

...

<section class="section_two">
  <ng-container *ngIf="someCondition; else someTemplate">
  </ng-container>
</section>

...

<ng-template #someTemplate>
  ...
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accidentally (not searching for this problem in specific), I went to something exactly equal what I was wanting in this question:

https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet

Something like that should work:

```
<section class="section_one">
  <ng-container
    *ngIf="someCondition"
    *ngTemplateOutlet="someTemplate"
  ></ng-container>
</section>

<section class="section_two">
  <ng-container
    *ngIf="!someCondition"
    *ngTemplateOutlet="someTemplate"
  ></ng-container>
</section>

<ng-template #someTemplate>
  ...
</ng-template>
```